# Wikipedia, complete measure and measure produce

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

On this page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure

one can find that:[image]

I am surprised by the paragraph talking about the vitali set. How on earth can you take :

$$ \lambda^2 ( \{0\} \times A) $$

when $$ A \notin \mathcal B $$

I believe, one can only take sets in $ \mathcal B \times \mathcal B$ or do I misunderstand something ?

any idea is welcomed, thanks.

Comment: You can't. It says right there in front of you that $\lambda^2(\{0\}\times A)$  is undefined - that's the whole point.

Comment: So what is the whole point of that article?

Comment: Read the first sentence:  The point is to use product spaces to "illustrate the  need to consider questions of completeness".

Comment: Thank you @DavidC.Ullrich for your answer but I don't understand the whole point of the article. That was the starting point of my research, why are completion spaces important and this example isn't enlighting anything, do you mind please detailing your answer a little bit ?